# Attempting to reverse engineer an iOS OTA payload-like archival format

Tags: file-format, ios, osx

Apple's announcement of macOS Big Sur had meant the release of the developer beta. In an attempt to create the appbundle from Apple's `softwarecatalog`, [I attempted to study the contents of `InstallAssistant.pkg`](https://kittywhiskers.eu/the-chronicles-of-big-sur/). In the process, I found `pbzx` files in the `payloadv2` directory that mimic Format 3.0 used by iOS for its' OTA updates and [the study of that format by Johnathan Levin](http://newosxbook.com/articles/OTA8.html) and attempted to use his `ota` tool to extract it (which uses the following struct)

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct entry
{

    unsigned int usually_0x210_or_0x110;
    unsigned short  usually_0x00_00; //_00_00;
    unsigned int  fileSize;
    unsigned short whatever;
    unsigned long long timestamp_likely;
    unsigned short _usually_0x20;
    unsigned short nameLen;
    unsigned short uid;
    unsigned short gid;
    unsigned short perms;
    char name[0];
// Followed by file contents
};

#pragma pack()
```

There was no avail with `ota` so I resorted to use a slightly modified (in terms of memory improvements) version of his `pbzx` tool to extract the stream, to success using the bash command given below in the `payloadv2` directory

`rm *.ecc && find *.??? -exec bash -c "./pbzx {} >> {}.unpbzx" \; && mkdir unpbzx && mv *.unpbzx unpbzx/`

As a result I now have a directory full of `.unpbzx` files. Attempting to run `ota` (with `pbzx` support removed to eliminate the possibility of potential bugs there) on `payload.000.unpbzx` results in a Segmentation Fault, `gdb` returns

```
Corrupt entry (0x31414159 at pos 30@0x10100001e).. skipping

Thread 2 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000001000031b4 in processFile (FileName=0x7ffeefbff74e "/Volumes/[redacted]/pbzx/payload.000.unpbzx") at ota.c:423
423                 while (ent->usually_0x210_or_0x110 != 0x210 && ent->usually_0x210_or_0x110 != 0x110)
```

Running it with alternative tools like `ota2tar` (with `pbzx` extraction code removed) and forks of `ota` like `iOS-Utilities` gave similar errors (out-of-bounds memory errors, etc.)

It appears that somehow this `unpbzx` file has a different header structure to the description of [Format 3.0 on the iPhone Wiki](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/OTA_Updates)

Opening `payload.000.unpbzx` with Hex Fiend shows that the file format appears to be differing from the struct given above (singular entry highlighted)

[image: Hex Fiend showing an odd format with magic phrase YAA1]

Files seem to be listed with some form of delimiter `YAA1` in the beginning. Isolating individual entries gives results similar to the image given below (file name highlighted)

[image: Photograph of hex string with singular entry, highlighting of path]

My knowledge of reverse engineering is admittedly limited so the best I could do is some psudocode about what the struct may look like

```
struct entry
{
  uint8_t header; // 59414131 (0xYAA1) 
  uint32_t description; // 69005459 50314450 41545030 (iTYP1DPATP)
  uint8_t padding; // 00
  // fileNameLen undefined
  char[fileNameLen] filename; // System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.28/Net/LDAP/Control
  uint8_t uid; // 55494431 (or 0xUID1)
  uint8_t padding2; // 00
  uint8_t descr_end; // 474944 31004D4F 4432ED01 464C4734 00000800 4D544D54
  // (descr_end includes GID, MOD and FLG values)
  // file_contents
}
```

As a last ditch attempt, I ran `payload.000.unpbzx` through 7zip and it identifies the file as a `gzip` stream

```
Path = /Volumes/[redacted]/pbzx/payload.000.unpbzx
Type = gzip
ERRORS:
There are data after the end of archive
Offset = 5636247
Physical Size = 98
Tail Size = 12327687
Headers Size = 10
Streams = 1

ERROR: There is some data after the end of the payload data : payload.000

Sub items Errors: 1
Archives with Errors: 1
Open Errors: 1
```

But `gunzip` does not recognize the format.

**At this point, what would be the best way of interpreting this new archival structure and how do I proceed forward?**

*(Note: Hex Fiend displays `000.pbzx` because I did actually name the files with the `.pbzx` extension even though that naming was incorrect and had modified it to `.unpbzx` for clarity in this question)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`YAA` is possibly the signature of [yaa archives](https://wwws.nightwatchcybersecurity.com/2020/06/14/yaa-an-obscure-macos-compressed-file-format/), so try using the `yaa` utility on those files.

Comment: Never heard of the `yaa` format before, searching for the magic number yielded nothing on Google. Some files seem to be extracted but eventually it reaches `YP1DPATP | Error 0x8704c800 | Invalid header | 96504 entries failed to extract`. Using the graphical utility, I get a more generic `Error 32 - Broken Pipe` (and attempting to run it on the non-concat'ed archive gives a familiar `Operation Not Permitted`). The article detailing use is [only two weeks old](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/133985). **+1 for showing the way :)**

Answer (score 0):

See: http://newosxbook.com/articles/OTA8.html

(and prior episodes)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1 
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/stat.h> // for mkdir
#include <sys/mman.h> // for mmap

#undef ntohl
#undef ntohs



#define RED     "\033[0;31m"
#define M0      "\e[0;30m"
#define CYAN    "\e[0;36m"
#define M1      "\e[0;31m"
#define GREY    "\e[0;37m"
#define M8      "\e[0;38m"
#define M9      "\e[0;39m"
#define GREEN   "\e[0;32m"
#define YELLOW  "\e[0;33m"
#define BLUE    "\e[0;34m"
#define PINK    "\e[0;35m"
#define NORMAL  "\e[0;0m"

#ifdef LINUX
typedef unsigned long uint64_t;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
extern void *memmem (const void *__haystack, size_t __haystacklen,
                     const void *__needle, size_t __needlelen);


#endif
/**
 *  Apple iOS OTA/PBZX expander/unpacker/lister/searcher - by Jonathan Levin,
 *
 *  http://NewOSXBook.com/
 *  
 *  Free for anyone (AISE) to use, modify, etc. I won't complain :-), but I'd appreciate a mention
 *
 * Changelog: 02/08/16 - Replaced alloca with malloc () (full OTAs with too many files would have popped stack..)
 *
 *            02/17/16 - Increased tolerance for corrupt OTA - can now seek to entry in a file
 *
 *            08/31/16 - Added search in OTA.
 * 
 *            02/28/18 - It's been a while - and ota now does diff!
 *                       Also tidied up and made neater
 *
 *            12/03/18 - Added -S to search for string null terminated
 *
 *            The last OTA: (seriously, I'm done :-)
 *
 *        08/06/19 - Integrated @S1guza's symlink fix (Thanks, man!)
 *                       Added pbzx built-in so you don't have to use pbzx first
 *                       Added multiple file processing, compatible with shell expansion
 *                         Can now ota ...whatever... payload.0?? to iterate over all files!
 *                       Added -H to generate SHA-1 hashes for all ('*') or specific files in OTA
 *             (SHA-1 code taken from public domain, as was lzma)
 *
 *  To compile: now use attached makefile, since there are lzma dependencies
 *          Remember to add '-DLINUX' if on Linux
 *
 *
 */
typedef     unsigned int    uint32_t;
uint64_t pos = 0;


#ifndef NOSHA
#include "sha1.c"
#endif // NOSHA
#pragma pack(1)
struct entry
{
 
 unsigned int usually_0x210_or_0x110;
 unsigned short  usually_0x00_00; //_00_00;
 unsigned int  fileSize;
 unsigned short whatever;
 unsigned long long timestamp_likely;
 unsigned short _usually_0x20;
 unsigned short nameLen;
 unsigned short uid;
 unsigned short gid;
 unsigned short perms;
 char name[0];
 // Followed by file contents
};

#pragma pack()

extern int ntohl(int);
extern short ntohs(short);
uint32_t    
swap32(uint32_t arg)
{
return (ntohl(arg));
}

int g_list = 0;
int g_verbose = 0;
char *g_extract = NULL;
char *g_search = NULL;
char *g_hash = NULL;
int g_nullTerm = 0;



// Since I now diff and use open->mmap(2) on several occasions, refactored 
// into its own function
//
void *mmapFile(char *FileName, uint64_t *FileSize)
{

    int fd = open (FileName, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) { perror (FileName); exit(1);}

    // 02/17/2016 - mmap
    
    struct stat stbuf;
    int rc = fstat(fd, &stbuf);

    char *mmapped =  mmap(NULL, // void *addr,
                  stbuf.st_size ,   // size_t len, 
                  PROT_READ,        // int prot,
                  MAP_PRIVATE,                //  int flags,
                  fd,               // int fd, 
                  0);               // off_t offset);


    if (mmapped == MAP_FAILED)  { perror (FileName); exit(1);}

    if (FileSize) *FileSize = stbuf.st_size;

    close (fd);
    return (mmapped);
}


void hashFile (char *File, char *Name, uint32_t Size, short Perms, char *HashCriteria)
{

    if (!HashCriteria) return;

    if ((HashCriteria[0] != '*') && ! strstr(Name, HashCriteria)) return ;
    
#define HASH_SIZE   20

    uint8_t Message_Digest[SHA1HashSize];

    doSHA1((void*)File, Size, Message_Digest);



    int i = 0;
    printf("%s (%d bytes): ", Name, Size);
    for (i = 0; i < HASH_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%02X", Message_Digest[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

}

void 
extractFile (char *File, char *Name, uint32_t Size, short Perms, char *ExtractCriteria)
{
    // MAYBE extract file (depending if matches Criteria, or "*").
    // You can modify this to include regexps, case sensitivity, what not. 
    // presently, it's just strstr()


    if (!ExtractCriteria) return;
    if ((ExtractCriteria[0] != '*') && ! strstr(Name, ExtractCriteria)) return;
    

    uint16_t type = Perms & S_IFMT;
        Perms &= ~S_IFMT;
        if(type != S_IFREG && type != S_IFLNK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unknown file type: %o\n", type);
                // return;
        }

    // Ok. Extract . This is simple - just dump the file contents to its directory.
    // What we need to do here is parse the '/' and mkdir(2), etc.
    
    char *dirSep = strchr (Name, '/');
    while (dirSep)
    {
        *dirSep = '\0';
        mkdir(Name,0755);
        *dirSep = '/';
        dirSep+=1;
        dirSep = strchr (dirSep, '/');
    }

    if(type == S_IFLNK) 
    {
    /* @s1guza's support for symlinks! */
    /* http://newosxbook.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=19513 */
        char *target = strndup(File, Size);
        if(g_verbose) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Symlinking %s to %s\n", Name, target);
        }
        symlink(target, Name);
        fchmodat(AT_FDCWD, Name, Perms, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW);
        free(target);
    }

    else  {
    // at this point we're out of '/'s
    // go back to the last /, if any
    
    if (g_verbose)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Dumping %d bytes to %s\n", Size, Name);
    }
    int fd = open (Name, O_WRONLY| O_CREAT);
    fchmod (fd, Perms);
    write (fd, File, Size);
    close (fd);

    }

} //  end extractFile

void showPos()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "POS is %lld\n", pos);
}

struct entry *getNextEnt (char *Mapping, uint64_t Size, uint64_t *Pos)
{
    // Return entry at Mapping[Pos],
    // and advance Pos to point to next one

    int pos = 0;
    struct entry *ent =(struct entry *) (Mapping + *Pos );

    if (*Pos > Size) return (NULL);
    *Pos += sizeof(struct entry);
    
    uint32_t entsize = swap32(ent->fileSize);
    uint32_t nameLen = ntohs(ent->nameLen);
        // Get Name (immediately after the entry)
        //char *name = malloc (nameLen+1);
        // strncpy(name, Mapping+ *Pos , nameLen);
        //name[nameLen] = '\0';
    //printf("NAME %p IS %s, Size: %d\n", Mapping, name, entsize);
    //free (name);
    *Pos += nameLen;
    *Pos += entsize;

    return (ent);

} // getNextEnt


int doDiff (char *File1, char *File2, int Exists)
{

    // There are two ways to do diff:
    // look at both files as archives, find diffs, then figure out diff'ing entry,
    // or look at file internal entries individually, then compare each of them
    // I chose the latter. This also (to some extent) survives file ordering

    // Note I'm still mmap(2)ing BOTH files. This contributes to speed, but does
    // have the impact of consuming lots o'RAM. That said, this is to be run on a 
    // Linux/MacOS, and not on an i-Device, so we should be ok.

    uint64_t file1Size = 0;

    char *file1Mapping = mmapFile(File1, &file1Size);
    uint64_t file2Size = 0;
    char *file2Mapping = mmapFile(File2, &file2Size);


    uint64_t file1pos = 0;
    uint64_t file2pos = 0;

    struct entry *file1ent = getNextEnt (file1Mapping, file1Size, &file1pos);
    struct entry *file2ent  = getNextEnt (file2Mapping,file2Size, &file2pos);

    uint64_t lastFile1pos, lastFile2pos = 0;

    while (file1ent && file2ent) {
        
        lastFile1pos = file1pos;
        lastFile2pos = file2pos;

        file1ent = getNextEnt (file1Mapping, file1Size, &file1pos);
        file2ent = getNextEnt (file2Mapping,file2Size, &file2pos);
        
        char *ent1Name = file1ent->name;
        char *ent2Name = file2ent->name;

        // Because I'm lazy: skip last entry
        if (file1pos > file1Size - 1000000) break;

        int found = 1;

        char *n1 = strndup(file1ent->name, ntohs(file1ent->nameLen));
        if (strncmp(ent1Name, ent2Name, ntohs(file1ent->nameLen)))
            {
                // Stupid names aren't NULL terminated (AAPL don't read my comments,
                // apparently), so we have to copy both names in:

                // But that's the least of our problems: We don't know if n1 has been removed
                // from n2, or n2 is a new addition:
                uint64_t seekpos = file2pos;    
                // seek n1 in file2:

                found = 0;
                int i = 0;

                struct entry *seek2ent;
                while (1) {
                    seek2ent = getNextEnt (file2Mapping,file2Size, &seekpos);
                    
                    if (!seek2ent) { break; } // {printf("EOF\n");break;}

                    if (memcmp(seek2ent->name,file1ent->name, ntohs(seek2ent->nameLen)) == 0) {
                
                        found++; break;
                    }
                    else {
/*
                        i++;
                        if (i < 200) {
                        char *n2 = strndup(seek2ent->name, ntohs(seek2ent->nameLen));

                        printf("check: %s(%d) != %s(%d) -- %d\n",n2, ntohs(seek2ent->nameLen),n1, strlen(n1),
                    memcmp(seek2ent->name,file1ent->name, ntohs(seek2ent->nameLen) ));
                        free(n2);

                        }
*/
                      }
                } // end while
                
                if (!found) { 
                        printf("%s: In file1 but not file2\n", n1);
                        // rewind file2pos so we hit the entry again..
                        file2pos = lastFile2pos;
                        }
                else {
                        // Found it - align (all the rest to this point were not in file1)
                        file2pos = seekpos;
                    }


            } // name mismatch

        if (found) {
            // Identical entries - check for diffs unless we're only doing existence checks

            // if the sizes diff, obviously:
            
            if (!Exists) {
            if (file1pos - lastFile1pos != file2pos - lastFile2pos)
                { fprintf(stdout,"%s (different sizes)\n", n1); }
            else
                // if sizes are identical, maybe - but ignore timestamp!
            if (memcmp (((unsigned char *)file1ent) + sizeof(struct entry), 
                    ((unsigned char *)file2ent) + sizeof(struct entry), file1pos - lastFile1pos - sizeof(struct entry)))
            { fprintf(stdout,"%s\n", n1); }

            }
        free (n1);
        }

    } // end file1pos
    return 0;
    

}

void processFile(char *fileName);

int 
main(int argc ,char **argv)
{

    char *filename ="p";
    int i = 0;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr,"Usage: %s [-v] [-l] [...] _filename[s]_ \nWhere: -l: list files in update payload\n"
                "Where: [...] is one of:\n"
                "       -e _file: extract file from update payload (use \"*\" for all files)\n"
                "       -s _string _file: Look for occurences of _string_ in file\n" 
                "       -S _string _file: Look for occurences of _string_, NULL terminated in file\n" 
                "       -H [_file]: get hash digest of specific file (use \"*\" for all files)\n"
                "       [-n] -d _file1 _file2: Point out differences between OTA _file1 and _file2\n"
                "                              -n to only diff names\n", argv[0]);
        exit(10);
        }
    
    int exists = 0;

    for (i = 1;
         (i < argc -1) && (argv[i][0] == '-');
         i++)
        {
        // This is super quick/dirty. You might want to rewrite with getopt, etc..
        
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-n") == 0) {
                    exists++;
            }
        else
        if (strcmp (argv[i] , "-d") == 0) { 
          // make sure we have argv[i+1] and argv[i+2]...

          if (i != argc - 3)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"-d needs exactly two arguments - two OTA files to compare\n");
                exit(6);
            }

          // that the files exist...
          if (access (argv[i+1], F_OK)) { fprintf(stderr,"%s: not a file\n", argv[i+1]); exit(11); }      
          if (access (argv[i+2], F_OK)) { fprintf(stderr,"%s: not a file\n", argv[i+2]); exit(12); }      
        
          // then do diff
          return ( doDiff (argv[i+1],argv[i+2], exists));
    
        }
        else
        if (strcmp (argv[i], "-l") == 0) { g_list++;} 
        else
        if (strcmp (argv[i] , "-v") == 0) { g_verbose++;}
#ifndef NOSHA
        else
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-H") == 0) {
            if (i == argc -1) { fprintf(stderr, "-H: Option requires an argument (what to extract)\n");
                        exit(5); }

            g_hash = argv[i+1]; i++;

        }
#endif
        else
        if (strcmp (argv[i], "-e") == 0) { 
            if (i == argc -1) { fprintf(stderr, "-e: Option requires an argument (what to extract)\n");
                        exit(5); }

            g_extract = argv[i+1]; i++;

        }

        // Added 08/31/16:
        // and modified 12/01/2018
        else
        if ((strcmp (argv[i], "-s") == 0) || (strcmp (argv[i], "-S") == 0))  { 
            if (i == argc - 2) { fprintf(stderr, "%s: Option requires an argument (search string)\n", argv[i]);
                        exit(5); }
            g_search = argv[i+1];
            if (argv[i][1] == 'S') g_nullTerm++;
            i++;     
            }
        else {
            fprintf(stderr,"Unknown option: %s\n", argv[i]);
            return 1;
            }

        
            

        }
    

    // Another little fix if user forgot filename, rather than try to open
    if (argv[argc-1][0] == '-') {
        fprintf(stderr,"Must supply filename\n"); exit(5);
    }

    
    // Loop over filenames:

    for (; i < argc; i++) 
    {
        if (strstr(argv[i],".ecc")) continue;
         processFile(argv[i]);
    }

}

#define PBZX_MAGIC  "pbzx"


char *doPBZX (char *pbzxData, int Size, int *ExtractedSize) {

#ifndef NO_PBZX
#define OUT_BUFSIZE     16*1024*1024 // Largest chunk I've seen is 8MB. This is double that.
char *  decompressXZChunk(char *buf, int size, char *Into, int *IntoSize);


    
    uint64_t length = 0, flags = 0;

   
    char *returned = malloc(OUT_BUFSIZE);
    int returnedSize = OUT_BUFSIZE;
    int available = returnedSize;

    int pos = strlen(PBZX_MAGIC);
    flags = *((uint64_t *) pbzxData + pos);

    // read (fd, &flags, sizeof (uint64_t));
    pos += sizeof(uint64_t);

    flags = __builtin_bswap64(flags);


   // fprintf(stderr,"Flags: 0x%llx\n", flags);

    int i = 0;
    int off = 0;

    int warn = 0 ;
    int skipChunk = 0;

    
    int rc = 0;
    // 03/09/2016 - Fixed for single chunks (payload.0##) files, e.g. WatchOS
    //              and for multiple chunks. AAPL changed flags on me..
    //
    // New OTAs use 0x800000 for more chunks, not 0x01000000.

    // 08/06/2019 - dang it. it's not flags - it's uncomp chunk size.

    uint64_t totalSize = 0;
    uint64_t uncompLen = flags;
    while (pos < Size){
    i++;
    //printf("FLAGS: %llx\n", flags);
    // rc= read (fd, &flags, sizeof (uint64_t)); // check retval..
    flags = *((uint64_t *) (pbzxData +pos));
    pos+= sizeof(uint64_t);
    flags = __builtin_bswap64(flags);
    //printf("FLAGS: %llx\n", flags);

    length = *((uint64_t *) (pbzxData +pos));
    //rc = read (fd, &length, sizeof (uint64_t));
    pos+= sizeof(uint64_t);
    length = __builtin_bswap64(length);

    skipChunk = 0; // (i < minChunk);
    if (getenv("JDEBUG") != NULL) fprintf(stderr,"Chunk #%d (uncomp: %lld, comp length: %lld bytes) %s\n",i, flags,length, skipChunk? "(skipped)":"");
     
    // Let's ignore the fact I'm allocating based on user input, etc..
    //char *buf = malloc (length);
    //int bytes = read (fd, buf, length);

    char *buf = pbzxData + pos;
    pos += length;
// flags = *((uint64_t *) (pbzxData +pos));

#if 0
    // 6/18/2017 - Fix for WatchOS 4.x OTA wherein the chunks are bigger than what can be read in one operation
    int bytes = length;
    int totalBytes = bytes;
    while (totalBytes < length) {
        // could be partial read
        bytes = read (fd, buf +totalBytes, length -totalBytes);
        totalBytes +=bytes;
        
    }   
#endif
    

   // We want the XZ header/footer if it's the payload, but prepare_payload doesn't have that, 
    // so just warn.
    
    if (memcmp(buf, "\xfd""7zXZ", 6))  { warn++; 
        fprintf (stderr, "Warning: Can't find XZ header. Instead have 0x%x(?).. This is likely not XZ data.\n",
            (* (uint32_t *) buf ));

        // Treat as uncompressed
        // UNCOMMENT THIS to handle uncomp XZ too..
        // write (1, buf, length);
        
        
        }
    else // if we have the header, we had better have a footer, too
    {
    if (strncmp(buf + length - 2, "YZ", 2)) { warn++; fprintf (stderr, "Warning: Can't find XZ footer at 0x%llx (instead have %x). This is bad.\n",
        (length -2),
        *((unsigned short *) (buf + length - 2))); 
        }
//  if (1 && !skipChunk)
    {
    // Uncompress chunk


    int chunkExpandedSize = available;
    char *ptrTo = returned + (returnedSize - available);
    decompressXZChunk(buf, length, returned + (returnedSize - available),&chunkExpandedSize);

    //  printf("DECOMPRESSING to %p - %p\n", ptrTo , ptrTo + chunkExpandedSize);
    totalSize += chunkExpandedSize;
    available -= chunkExpandedSize;
    if (available < OUT_BUFSIZE)
    {
        returnedSize += 10 * OUT_BUFSIZE;
        available +=  10 * OUT_BUFSIZE;
        // Can't use realloc!
        char *new = malloc(returnedSize);
        
        if (getenv("JDEBUG") != NULL)printf("REALLOCING from %p to %p ,%x, AVAIL: %x\n", returned,  new, returnedSize, available);
        if (new) {
         memcpy(new, returned, returnedSize - available);
         free(returned);
        returned = new;

        }
        else { fprintf(stderr,"ERROR!\n"); exit(1);}
    
    }
      

    }
    warn = 0;

    // free (buf);  // Not freeing anymore, @ryandesign :-)
    }

    }
    //printf("Total size: %d\n", totalSize);
    *ExtractedSize = totalSize;
    if (getenv("JDEBUG") != NULL)
    {
    int f = open ("/tmp/out1", O_WRONLY |O_CREAT);
    write (f, returned, totalSize);
    close(f);
    }
    return (returned);

#else
    fprintf(stderr,"Not compiled with PBZX support!\n");
    return (NULL);
#endif
} // pbzx

void processFile(char *FileName)
{
    int color = (getenv("JCOLOR")!= NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "%sProcessing %s%s\n", color ? RED: "", FileName, color ? NORMAL :"");

    //unsigned char buf[4096];

    uint64_t fileSize;

    uint64_t mappedSize;
    char *actualMmapped = mmapFile(FileName, &mappedSize);

    fileSize = mappedSize;

    if (actualMmapped == MAP_FAILED) { perror (FileName); return ;}



    char *mmapped = actualMmapped;
    char *extracted = NULL;
    // File could be a PBZX :-)
    if (memcmp(mmapped, PBZX_MAGIC, strlen(PBZX_MAGIC)) ==0)
    {
            // DO PBZX first!
            int extractedSize = 0;
            extracted = doPBZX (mmapped, mappedSize, &extractedSize);
            mmapped = extracted;
            fileSize = extractedSize;
        
    //  printf("EXTRACTED: %p, size: 0x%llx\n",mmapped, fileSize);


    }

    int i = 0;

    struct entry *ent = alloca (sizeof(struct entry));

    pos = 0;
    while(pos + 3*sizeof(struct entry) < fileSize) {

    ent = (struct entry *) (mmapped + pos );
    pos += sizeof(struct entry);

    if ((ent->usually_0x210_or_0x110 != 0x210 && ent->usually_0x210_or_0x110 != 0x110 &&
        ent->usually_0x210_or_0x110 != 0x310) || 
        ent->usually_0x00_00)
    {
        fprintf (stderr,"Corrupt entry (0x%x at pos %llu@0x%llx).. skipping\n", ent->usually_0x210_or_0x110,
            pos, (uint64_t)(mmapped+pos));
        int skipping = 1;

        while (skipping)
        {
           ent = (struct entry *) (mmapped + pos ) ;
           while (ent->usually_0x210_or_0x110 != 0x210 && ent->usually_0x210_or_0x110 != 0x110)
           {
             // #@$#$%$# POS ISN'T ALIGNED!
             pos ++;
            ent = (struct entry *) (mmapped + pos ) ;
           }
           // read rest of entry
            int nl = ntohs(ent->nameLen);

            if (ent->usually_0x00_00 || !nl) {
        //   fprintf(stderr,"False positive.. skipping %d\n",pos);
            pos+=1;
            

            }
            else { skipping =0;
               pos += sizeof(struct entry); }
            if (pos > fileSize) return;
        }

    }

    uint32_t    size = swap32(ent->fileSize);

// fprintf(stdout," Here - ENT at pos %d: %x and 0 marker is %x namelen: %d, fileSize: %d\n", pos, ent->usually_0x210_or_0x110, ent->usually_0x00_00, ntohs(ent->nameLen), size);

    uint32_t    nameLen = ntohs(ent->nameLen);
    // Get Name (immediately after the entry)
    //
    // 02/08/2016: Fixed this from alloca() - the Apple jumbo OTAs have so many files in them (THANKS GUYS!!)
    // that this would exceed the stack limits (could solve with ulimit -s, or also by using
    // a max buf size and reusing same buf, which would be a lot nicer)

    
    // Note to AAPL: Life would have been a lot nicer if the name would have been NULL terminated..
    // What's another byte per every file in a huge file such as this?
    // char *name = (char *) (mmapped+pos);

    char *name = alloca (nameLen+1);

    strncpy(name, mmapped+pos , nameLen);
    name[nameLen] = '\0';
    //printf("NAME IS %s\n", name);

    pos += ntohs(ent->nameLen);
    uint32_t    fileSize = swap32(ent->fileSize);
    uint16_t    perms = ntohs(ent->perms);  


    if (g_list){ 
    if (g_verbose) {
    printf ("Entry @0x%d: UID: %d GID: %d Mode: %o Size: %d (0x%x) Namelen: %d Name: ", i,
                            ntohs(ent->uid), ntohs(ent->gid),
                             perms, size, size,
                              ntohs(ent->nameLen));
    }
    printf ("%s\n", name);}


    // Get size (immediately after the name)
    if (fileSize) 
        {
            if (g_extract) { extractFile(mmapped +pos, name, fileSize, perms, g_extract);}
            // Added  08/05/19 -  Hash
            if (g_hash) { hashFile (mmapped +pos, name, fileSize, perms, g_hash); }

    
            // Added 08/31/16 - And I swear I should have this from the start.
            // So darn simple and sooooo useful!

            if (g_search){
    
                char *found = memmem (mmapped+pos, fileSize, g_search, strlen(g_search) + (g_nullTerm ? 1 : 0));
                while (found != NULL)
                {
                int relOffset = found - mmapped - pos;
                
                fprintf(stdout, "Found in Entry: %s, relative offset: 0x%x (Absolute: %lx)",
                    name,
                    relOffset,
                    found - mmapped);

                // 12/01/18

                if (g_verbose) {

                fputc(':', stdout);
                fputc(' ', stdout);
                   char *begin = found;

                   int i = 0 ;
#define BACK_LIMIT -20
#define FRONT_LIMIT 20
                   while(begin[i] && i > BACK_LIMIT) { i--;}
                   
                   for (;begin +i < found; i++) { 

                    if (isprint(begin[i])) putc (begin[i], stdout); else putc ('.', stdout); }
                   printf("%s%s%s",RED, g_search, NORMAL);
                   for (i+= strlen(g_search); begin[i] &&( i < FRONT_LIMIT); i++) { 
                    if (isprint(begin[i])) putc (begin[i], stdout); else putc ('.', stdout); }
                                    
                     

                }
                fprintf(stdout,"\n");

                // keep looking..
                 found = memmem (found + 1, fileSize - relOffset , g_search, strlen(g_search) +( g_nullTerm ? 1: 0));
                } // end while
                
            } // end g_search

            pos +=fileSize;
        }



    

    } // Back to loop

    if (extracted) { /*printf("FREEing %p\n", extracted);*/ free (extracted);}
    munmap(actualMmapped, mappedSize);


    
}
```